# Newbie to twisted and cyclone - How to get redis callbacks to work for a simple get request

Tags: python, redis, twisted, tornado, cyclone

Below is my code for trying to redis in a non blocking method from a get request to write to redis.  Also below is the the error I get.  It a 500 error. I just dont understand the documenation for txredisapi that shipped with cyclone.  It did write to redis but the app

```
import cyclone.web
import sys
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log
import cyclone.redis as redis
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet import reactor

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def redisPixelWrite(remote_ip):
    rc = yield redis.Connection()
    yield rc.set("foo", 'itwodasdfred')
    v = yield rc.get("foo")
    print "foo:", v
    yield rc.disconnect()

class Application(cyclone.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
        ]
        settings = {"xheaders": True,"static_path": "./static"}
        cyclone.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)       

class MainHandler(cyclone.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        remote_ip = self.request.remote_ip
        redisPixelWrite(remote_ip).addcallback()
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.write(remote_ip)

def main():
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    reactor.listenTCP(8051, Application(), interface="127.0.0.1")
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


2012-05-07 21:12:10+0800 [-] Log opened.
2012-05-07 21:12:10+0800 [-] Application starting on 8051
2012-05-07 21:12:10+0800 [-] Starting factory <__main__.Application instance at 0x228af38>
2012-05-07 21:12:14+0800 [HTTPConnection,0,127.0.0.1] Starting factory <cyclone.redis.RedisFactory instance at 0x261a680>
2012-05-07 21:12:14+0800 [HTTPConnection,0,127.0.0.1] Uncaught exception GET / (127.0.0.1) :: HTTPRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8051', method='GET', uri='/', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', body='', headers={'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:8051', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0'})
2012-05-07 21:12:14+0800 [HTTPConnection,0,127.0.0.1] 500 GET / (127.0.0.1) 2.07ms
2012-05-07 21:12:14+0800 [RedisProtocol,client] foo: itwodasdfred
2012-05-07 21:12:14+0800 [RedisProtocol,client] Stopping factory <cyclone.redis.RedisFactory instance at 0x261a680>
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed some things in the code.

1. The `get` function must be decorated with `inlineCallbacks`, and it should `yield redisPixelWrite(remote_ip)`
2. You probably don't want to make a new connection to redis on every request. It's more efficient to set up a persistent connection pool, and reuse it on new requests.

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
import cyclone.redis
import cyclone.web
import sys

from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet import reactor


class RedisMixin(object):
    redis = None

    @classmethod
    def setup(self):
        RedisMixin.redis = cyclone.redis.lazyConnectionPool()


class Application(cyclone.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [(r"/", MainHandler)]
        RedisMixin.setup()
        settings = {"debug": True, "xheaders": True, "static_path": "./static"}
        cyclone.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)


class MainHandler(cyclone.web.RequestHandler, RedisMixin):
    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def get(self):
        try:
            yield self.redis.set("foo", self.request.remote_ip)
            ip = yield self.redis.get("foo")
        except:
            raise cyclone.web.HTTPError(503)  # Service Unavailable
        else:
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.write(ip)


def main():
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    reactor.listenTCP(8051, Application(), interface="127.0.0.1")
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that the default behaviour of all `Connection` methods is to auto reconnect should redis be stopped, or restarted. It'll respond with HTTP 503 (Service Unavailable) until the connection is re-established and communication with redis is resumed.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
redisPixelWrite(remote_ip).addcallback()
```

raise `AttributeError`.  You should probably file a bug report against Cyclone, as it should have been reporting this somewhere (alternatively, make sure you're actually looking at the log where exceptions would be reported).

`redisPixelWrite` returns a `Deferred` because it is decorated with `inlineCallbacks`.  There is no `addcallback` method on `Deferred`.  There is an `addCallback` method, and I suppose that may be what you wanted to use.  It takes at least one argument, though, not zero, so you need to fix that as well.